# Why is it that not all final constant strings are created equal in java

Tags: java, android, string, switch-statement, constants

I made a crazy discovery today in Java and I would like to know why.

The following switch statement **works**

```
public static final String OTHER_OTHER = ”.otherOther”;
…
        switch (SWITCHER) {
            case Dogs.OTHER_OTHER:
                doMyWork(intent);
                break;
            default:
                ...;
        }
```

**Fails to compile**

```
public static final String OTHER_OTHER = Dogs.class.getPackage().toString()+”.otherOther”;
…
        switch (SWITCHER) {
            case Dogs.OTHER_OTHER:
                doMyWork(intent);
                break;
            default:
                ...;
        }
```

The only difference between the two snippets is in how I constructed the constant OTHER_OTHER

The second switch statement is complaining that OTHER_OTHER is not a constant. I am creating a String of all thing, using `final`.

Comment: Is the OTHER_OTHER evaluating to the same value in both of them.

Comment: I don't get the question. I am creating a String using `final String` does that not make it a constant?

Comment: What does 'not work' mean? Does not compile? Produces unexpected result?

Comment: It's hard to find, but the OP does say the compiler balks at the constant declaration.

Comment: It looks like someone who knows nothing about java down voted my question. Thanks to whoever corrected with an up vote.

Answer (score 3):

`Dogs.class.getPackage().toString()` is not a constant, it uses the reflection API to retrieve the package during runtime through the class-loader. So those examples are not equivalent.

Comment: You might add that constant values have to be resolvable at compile time, and the expression in the non-working version cannot be known until runtime.

Comment: Well, it is "constant" at run-time. but it is not a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: @JimGarrison I believe it is correcter to say that an expression is only considered constant if it can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Thilo Which is not constant, I've seen people do some insane stuff with custom classloaders

Comment: My "constant" in quotes refers to "never changes after initially calculated" (which is the case here, as the field is final, and is what many people would consider a constant). But that does not matter. To be constant as per the JLS it needs to be resolved at compile-time. The switch statement makes use of that by inlining pre-calculated hashcodes into the class file.

Comment: @Thilo Fair enough. In some cases the difference between a "constant expression" and a "constant variable" is vague.

Comment: Thank you so much for the discussion. Although the response itself does not answer the question and so I am not able to credit it as the answer, the discussion does indeed answer the question. The reason I cannot check it as the answer, I don't want someone else to come here, read it and don't read the discussions, and think that is the answer.